# Login functionality in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using web api and creating a login functionality.(n tier architecture).
I am getting a null response in Login Controller.

First  I want to confirm that is my code logic is correct and if it is correct then why i am getting response null in

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Login/Login").Result;
```

My Project UI Login Controller Code 
LoginCOntroller.cs

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:63465/");

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Login/Login").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Project");
            }
            return View(loginViewModel);
        }
```

My Api Login Controller Code
LoginController.cs

```
public HttpResponseMessage Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        userEntity.Email = loginViewModel.UserName;
        userEntity.Password = loginViewModel.Password;

        var login = new LoginManager().LoginAuthentication(userEntity);

        if (login != null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(login);
        }
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(true);
}
```

My Login manager Class
LoginManager.cs

```
  public class LoginManager
    {

    public UserEntity LoginAuthentication(UserEntity userDetails)
    {
        var userDetail = new LoginDa().LoginAuthentication(userDetails);
        return userDetail;
    }
}
```

My Data access layer
LoginDa.cs

```
public class LoginDa
{
    public UserEntity LoginAuthentication(UserEntity login)
    {
        using (var context = new ArcomDbContext())
        {
            var loginDetail = context.userInformation.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Email == login.Email && p.Password == login.Password);
            return loginDetail;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your routing code?

Comment: This is my Route.config `        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }`

Comment: have you added a [Httpget] annotation above LoginController?

Comment: @KasperDue [Httpget] annotation for Api LoginController

Comment: i mean a [HttpGet] annotation above your Login action inside your API LoginController.

Comment: @KasperDue yes i have added

Comment: In your UI Login controller, you are making a [HttpPost] annotation, while making a get request, try change it to httpget instead

Answer (score 1):

`GetAsync` method will only call GET methods on your API, so if you have prefixed your method in API with `[HttpPost]` (which it should be) you need to call POST methods of `HttpClient` class (For example - `PostAsJsonAsync`).

Secondly you're not following the `async`/`await` pattern? You're calling an `async` method, but not awaiting it.

More on that here http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html .

With all that said below is how your code should look

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:63465");
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/login", loginViewModel); //Since it's a post it will automatically trigger corresponding post method on your webAPI
    if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Project");
    }
    return View(loginViewModel);
}
```

Also are you able to call you API using fiddler/Postman ?